# How can I edit the markup of a note in Evernote directly (Windows)?

Tags: windows, editing, evernote, markup

I am looking to be able to remove, and update notes within the Windows [Evernote client](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/windows.php).

The editor is moderately powerful, but I would like to edit the markup directly.

I'm not even sure if Evernote uses html, markdown, or some special, proprietary markup.

How can I edit the notes directly?

Comment: From the examination of Evernote local files folder (you may find it's location at Evernote Options dialog) it seems that Evernote stores notes in a proprietary way in SQLite database. You may examine the database with any SQLite editor, but I don't recommend altering it without complete understanding of its structure.

Comment: Is that the only way to grab the contents? If so, too bad, it doesn't seem worth the trouble in that case. But thanks very much for your help and comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just come across [ENML Editor](http://enml-editor.ping13.net/), which, as its name suggests, is an Evernote markup language editor, allowing you to directly manipulate (and potentially screw up) the underlying markup in an EN note.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the note from the Windows client as a .enex (Evernote Export format) - then open that file in your favourite editor (it's just XML) and fiddle with the HTML; then import it back into Evernote. Be careful of the structure though!

Alternatively, the web version of Evernote uses a customized version of TinyMCE editor; these support having events injected, and you can inject the mceCodeEditor event to popup an html editor for the current note. Obviously it relies quite heavily on the implementation of the Evernote web page, and isn't supported in anyway by the Evernote team!

The second TinyMCE instance on the page is the active note; so you can get an HTML editor by running this JavaScript on the page:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceCodeEditor',false, tinymce.editors[1].id);
```

If you want a bookmarklet that does exactly that (i.e. I've done it for you!), see here 
http://seb.so/html-source-editor-for-evernote-web-a-bookmarklet/ for more details